# How can I remove the duplicate pages from EJS template pagination?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pagination, ejs

I have found this [article](https://evdokimovm.github.io/javascript/nodejs/mongodb/pagination/expressjs/ejs/bootstrap/2017/08/20/create-pagination-with-nodejs-mongodb-express-and-ejs-step-by-step-from-scratch.html) for implementing a pagination feature in my MEN stack app. The article shows everything from frontend to backend. Everything works fine but I'm trying to tweak it a little.

The demo app from the article looks like this:

[image]

But I replaced the `First` and `Last` from the start and the end and used `1` and `10`, but now I have a duplicate of 1 and 10. Like this:

[image]

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<% if (pages > 1) { %>

     <ul class="pagination-list">

             <% if (currentPage == 1) { %>

                        <li class="disabled"><a>1</a></li>

             <% } else { %>

                        <li><a href="/1">1</a></li>

             <% } %>


             <% var i = (Number(currentPage) > 5 ? Number(currentPage) - 4 : 1) %>


             <% if (i !== 1) { %>

                        <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>

             <% } %>


             <% for (; i <= (Number(currentPage) + 4) && i <= pages; i++) { %>

                  <% if (i == currentPage) { %>

                            <li class="active"><a><%= i %></a></li>

                  <% } else { %>

                            <li><a href="/<%= i %>"><%= i %></a></li>

                  <% } %>

                  <% if (i == Number(currentPage) + 4 && i < pages) { %>

                            <li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>

                  <% } %>

             <% } %>


             <% if (currentPage == pages) { %>

                     <li class="disabled"><a><%= pages %></a></li>

             <% } else { %>

                     <li><a href="/<%= pages %>"><%= pages %></a></li>

             <% } %>
    </ul>

<% } %>
```

How can I remove the duplicate ones?

*** Thanks to [Mikhail Evdokimov](https://evdokimovm.github.io/) for the tutorial. ***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the for loop to: `for (; i <= (Number(currentPage) + 4) && i < pages; i++) {`

That should do the trick for the `10` you want to remove. Hope it works, not sure it will, can't test it right now.

If you won't get it working in like 2 hours, I can help you then, when I could test it on my example.

**Edit**:

The 10 got removed. We simply changed "less than or equal" to "less than", meaning the last for cycle didn't get executed because we were at the last cycle of the last page already.

Now for the `1`:

```
var i = (Number(currentPage) > 5 ? Number(currentPage) - 4 : 1)
```

You should change this `i` declaration. What this code tells us is:

```
If the number of the current page is higher than 5 do:
Number(currentPage) - 4
else
1
```

And because we are using the `i` variable as a starting point in our for loop, we should change the `1` to `2`.

So the correct declaration should be:

```
var i = (Number(currentPage) > 5 ? Number(currentPage) - 4 : 2)
```

**Second edit:**

Now for the `...` problem:

You can probably change `i !== 1` to `i !== 2`

That should fix it, it's the same principle, we are starting for loop from `2`, so we have to change it to `2`. We are telling it: don't show `...` when we are on pages: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` now.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your time. Yes, it did remove the 10. Perfectly as I imagined. However, how can I remove the 1?

Comment: And yes it's no problem. I can wait a million hours. I just badly need the help.

Comment: @A.Amit Edited the original answer, check it above, consider marking my answer as solved if it helped, thanks

Comment: Yo. It got removed perfectly. You are a genius. But bro that raised another issue. Right now if I am in page 1 the pages look like this - ```1 ... 2 3 4 5  ... 10```. The beginning ```...``` is not necessary until page 4-5 I suppose right?

Comment: @A.Amit You are right, you can probably change `i !== 1` to `i !== 2`

That should fix it, it's the same principle, we are starting from 2, so we have to change it to 2.